# How do I (only) update the timestamp of an OPC UA Node using an Eclipse Milo OpcUa Server?

Tags: java, datetime, opc-ua, instant, milo

Thanks for reading this post. I am gratefull for every help!

**Goal:**

I am trying to write a ValueNode with the same value, but different timestamp on an Eclipse Milo OpcUa Server. I'm doing all this with Java 11 and Milo 0.3.7.

I tested it among others with the example in the github project. I modified the function addScalarNodes in the class ExampleNamespace to write the same value with an updated timestamp once a second. Checking the node with UaExpert, the timestamp remains on the same value. Only if I update the value too, the timestamp updates.

```
private void addScalarNodes(UaFolderNode rootNode) {
        UaFolderNode scalarTypesFolder = new UaFolderNode(
            getNodeContext(),
            newNodeId("HelloWorld/ScalarTypes"),
            newQualifiedName("ScalarTypes"),
            LocalizedText.english("ScalarTypes")
        );

        getNodeManager().addNode(scalarTypesFolder);
        rootNode.addOrganizes(scalarTypesFolder);

        for (Object[] os : STATIC_SCALAR_NODES) {
            String name = (String) os[0];
            NodeId typeId = (NodeId) os[1];
            Variant variant = (Variant) os[2];

            UaVariableNode node = new UaVariableNode.UaVariableNodeBuilder(getNodeContext())
                .setNodeId(newNodeId("HelloWorld/ScalarTypes/" + name))
                .setAccessLevel(ubyte(AccessLevel.getMask(AccessLevel.READ_WRITE)))
                .setUserAccessLevel(ubyte(AccessLevel.getMask(AccessLevel.READ_WRITE)))
                .setBrowseName(newQualifiedName(name))
                .setDisplayName(LocalizedText.english(name))
                .setDataType(typeId)
                .setTypeDefinition(Identifiers.BaseDataVariableType)
                .build();

            node.setValue(new DataValue(variant));

            node.setAttributeDelegate(new ValueLoggingDelegate());

            getNodeManager().addNode(node);
            scalarTypesFolder.addOrganizes(node);

            if (name.equals("Boolean")) {
                Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000L);
                            node.setValue(new DataValue(new Variant(Boolean.FALSE)));
                            System.out.println(node.getValue().getSourceTime());
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Question(s):**

1) Is updating the timestamp only allowed in OPC UA specs.

2) How can I achive this with Milo?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I check the timestamp by active reading:

Server-side writing:

```
private void handleValueUpdate(Object value, DateTime dateTime) {
        node.setValue(new DataValue(
            new Variant(value),
            StatusCode.GOOD,
            dateTime));
    }
```

Client-side reading:

```
VariableNode variableNode = getOpcClient().getAddressSpace().getVariableNode(new NodeId(namespaceIndex, nodeIdentifier)).get();
return variableNode.readValue().get().getSourceTime();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking by reading (refreshing attributes pane) or with a subscription and monitored item?

If you're using MonitoredItems the default MonitoringFilter when not otherwise specified uses `DataChangeTrigger.StatusValue`, which includes changes to value or quality, but not timestamp, so most clients will not ask for or receive timestamp-only changes by default.

Comment: Yes, I check by reading. See code snippets above for details. I assume, that this is not affected by the `DataChangeTrigger.StatusValue` you mentined above.

Comment: Using your original example code (the thread that updates the value) I see both Source and Server timestamps updating in UaExpert when I refresh the attributes pane for the Boolean scalar node.

Comment: I also see the update when modifying one of the Read service examples.

Comment: I managed to get it running. I had the DataChangeTrigger wrong in UaExpert, as you suggested. I wasn't aware of that, which lead to my first assumption, that milo handles timestamps different than expected.
Second I had a minor detail wrong in the code of my test scenario (not the code I posted).
Big thanks to @KevinHerron !